# Problems with a PAINT program in PyGame

Tags: python, class, pygame, mouse, paint

So, I am a beginner level programmer, and I thought that It would be cool to make a Paint Program in PyGame (Python).

I've had a few problems while doing so:

```
import pygame


class Brush:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, radius, location, center):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.location = location
        self.center = center

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.location, self.color, self.center, self.radius)

    def getMouse(self):
        pass




pygame.init()

brushX = 400
brushY = 300

colorWhite = (255, 255, 255)
radius = 15

thickness = 0

width = 800
height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Paint")


brush = Brush(colorWhite, brushX, brushY, radius, screen, pos)

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()



    brush.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Above is my code.

So, My Problem is How do I get the mouse position actively, and change it in the class for Brush?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

to get the position of the mouse, it returns a tuple so if you want to assign it to two different variables then you can do something like this:

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

To add it to your code you might want to do something like this:

```
while run:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
brush.x = mouseX
brush.y = mouseY

brush.draw()
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: No problem :)))